# Wait for multiple AsyncTask to complete

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I am parallelizing my operation by splitting it in the exact number of cores available and then, by start the same number of AsyncTask, performing the same operation but on different portions of data.

I am using `executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, ...)` in order to parallelize the execution of them.

I would like to know when every thread finishes its job so that combine all results and perform further operations.

How can I do?

Comment: If you want to wait, then I would prefer using Thread as you can simply join a thread. The whole point of using Async is that it executes in parallel. Sure you can wait for result by using Future for Async.

Comment: Do you have control over the `AsyncTask`s and do you know the number of tasks in advance? if so, you can just count down (integer variable, no fancy synchroniziation needed) the number of finished tasks in `onPostExecute()` and act when the count reaches zero.

Comment: @dhke in this case you have to run an idle loop and I do not like it too much

Comment: @NicholasAllio Does this refer to my deleted comment? If so: Yes, I realized from your comments on the answers that you want to be notified, not wait.

Comment: Use Rx merge operator

Comment: With this approach two questions raises: What happens if something goes wrong? Can *AsyncTask* handle Errors?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could also simply decrement a counter in a shared object as part of `onPostExecute`. As `onPostExecute` runs on the same thread (the main thread), you won't have to worry about synchronization.

**UPDATE 1**

The shared object could look something like this:

```
public class WorkCounter {
    private int runningTasks;
    private final Context ctx;

    public WorkCounter(int numberOfTasks, Context ctx) {
        this.runningTasks = numberOfTasks;
        this.ctx = ctx;
    }
    // Only call this in onPostExecute! (or add synchronized to method declaration)
    public void taskFinished() {
        if (--runningTasks == 0) {
            LocalBroadcastManager mgr = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this.ctx);
            mgr.sendBroadcast(new Intent("all_tasks_have_finished"));
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

According to the comments for this answer, OP is looking for a solution in which he can avoid building a new class. This can be done by sharing an `AtomicInteger` among the spawned `AsyncTask`s:

```
// TODO Update type params according to your needs.
public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {
    // This instance should be created before creating your async tasks.
    // Its start count should be equal to the number of async tasks that you will spawn.
    // It is important that the same AtomicInteger is supplied to all the spawned async tasks such that they share the same work counter.
    private final AtomicInteger workCounter;

    public MyAsyncTask(AtomicInteger workCounter) {
        this.workCounter = workCounter;
    }

    // TODO implement doInBackground

    @Override
    public void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // Job is done, decrement the work counter.
        int tasksLeft = this.workCounter.decrementAndGet();
        // If the count has reached zero, all async tasks have finished.
        if (tasksLeft == 0) {
            // Make activity aware by sending a broadcast.
            LocalBroadcastManager mgr = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this.ctx);
            mgr.sendBroadcast(new Intent("all_tasks_have_finished"));    
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think in this way you may have problem of multiple access and modification of the same variable by multiple threads if they finish at the same time..

Comment: No, as onPostExecute is run on the main thread. Just don't access the variable as part of doInBackground.

Comment: So you will propose to let the activity wait in an idle loop till the counter reaches zero? Not sure is the best solution then..

Comment: No, that would definitely not be a good solution (in fact the activity would probably be closed by the system due to unresponsiveness). You could instead, as part of setting the counter in your shared object, check if the updated value has reached 0. If that is the case, do a local broadcast and listen for that inside your activity.

Comment: For sure this will work but I was looking for something more handy

Comment: What do you mean by more handy? Builtin functionality? Added example of the proposed class. It's pretty simply IMO.

Comment: Handy in a sense that I would avoid to build a new class exclusively for this purpose

Comment: I see. I have an alternative approach that you may like more (personally I would prefer the one posted). I will update the answer with the different strategy, give me a few minutes.

Comment: Added alternative solution that uses an AtomicInteger inside your existing AsyncTask implementation to deduce if all jobs have finished.

Comment: The upper solutions are bad and slow, use merge operator from Rx

Comment: @Duna you're arguing that it's slow to decrement an `int` variable in a shared object? This is _not_ a discussion of whether or not to use `AsyncTask` as the OP's question was in the context of `AsyncTask`s.

Answer (score 6):

You should use a CountDownLatch. Here the documentation with examples:
[java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html)

Basically you give a reference of CountDownLatch to your threads, and each of them will decrement it when finished:

```
countDownLatch.countDown();
```

The main thread will wait on the termination of all threads using:

```
countDownLatch.await();
```

Comment: What is its behavior in case of concurrent access to the CountDownLatch?

Comment: It is thread safe as a CountDownLatch is a synchronization tool.

Comment: This solution is very interesting to me but the problem is that you can use it only if you do not have parameters to pass to your AsyncTask (in my case I pass to my task several Integers and I can not pass a CountDownLatch at the same time and refer to it in `onPostExecute` is not working properly

Comment: Maybe you could extend the AsyncTask and create a constructor with an extra parameter, and override the onPostExecute by calling 'super.onPostExecute()' and then 'countDownLatch.countDown()'.

Comment: "The _main thread_ will wait on the termination of all threads using: `countDownLatch.await()`" you'd actually need to dedicate a separate thread _other than the main thread_ for this `await` call as otherwise you'd be locking up the GUI (and thereby defeating the purpose of `AsyncTask`, i.e., to perform short-lived background jobs off of the main thread). Upon progressing beyond the `await` call, this thread dedicated for waiting would then have to signal back to the main thread that the jobs were completed by sending a broadcast or posting to a `Handler` associated with the main thread.

Answer (score 4):

First, add this class to your project

```
public abstract class MultiTaskHandler {
    private int mTasksLeft;
    private boolean mIsCanceled = false;

    public MultiTaskHandler(int numOfTasks) {
        mTasksLeft = numOfTasks;
    }

    protected abstract void onAllTasksCompleted();

    public void taskComplete()  {
        mTasksLeft--;
        if (mTasksLeft==0 && !mIsCanceled) {
            onAllTasksCompleted();
        }
    }

    public void reset(int numOfTasks) {
        mTasksLeft = numOfTasks;
        mIsCanceled=false;
    }

    public void cancel() {
        mIsCanceled = true;
    }
}
```

Then:

```
int totalNumOfTasks = 2; //change this to the number of tasks that you are running
final MultiTaskHandler multiTaskHandler = new MultiTaskHandler(totalNumOfTasks) {
    @Override
    protected void onAllTasksCompleted() {
       //put the code that runs when all the tasks are complete here
    }
};
```

Then in each task - when completed, add the line: `multiTaskHandler.taskComplete();`

Example:

```
(new AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>() {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        // do something...
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        multiTaskHandler.taskComplete();
    }
}).execute();
```

You can use `multiTaskHandler.cancel()` if you want to cancel the code that runs when all the tasks have completed. For instance - if you have an error (don't forget to also cancel all the other tasks).

*** This solution will not pause the main thread!**

Comment: This solution is just perfect.

Comment: Match very good with my personal problem, adapted it to my needs. Thumb up!

Answer (score 0):

Another Option could be to store all your new threads in an Array.

Then you could iterate over the Array and wait with thread[i].join for the thread to finish.

see join()
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html#Thread(java.lang.Runnable)

When the Iteration is finished all your threads are done and you can work on

Answer (score 0):

RX [Merge](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/merge.html) operator is your friend.

Get rid of AsyncTark is slower than RX and you cannot handle Errors