# How to execute instructions after multiple parallel AsyncTasks have finished running?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I wish to execute two AsyncTasks together like this:

```
new FetchProjetsTask().execute(projets.getId());
new FetchDashBoardsTask().execute(dashBoards.getId());
```

How can I wait for both of them to finish in order to execute other instructions?

(I am looking for a method similar to *onPostExecute* but for multiple AsyncTasks)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to put your head in new domains like `RxJava` and `Executors/Futures`, you may create new `AsyncTask` and call those 2 there in a blocking way.

```
doInBackground() {
    Result resultProjects = new FetchProjetsTask().execute(projets.getId()).get();
    Result resultDashboards= new FetchDashBoardsTask().execute(dashBoards.getId()).get();
    // continue with necessary logic
}
```

Please be aware, that `get()` [can throw exceptions](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#get()). However, if you don't need to use the result from both tasks to complete, you can implement solution with latches, like here [Wait for multiple AsyncTask to complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32625599/wait-for-multiple-asynctask-to-complete)

Answer (score 0):

My idea is to leverage the possibility of providing your own [executor](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService) to the AsyncTasks, using

```
new FetchProjetsTask().executeOnExecutor(yourExecutor, projets.getId());
new FetchDashBoardsTask().executeOnExecutor(yourExecutor, dashBoards.getId());
```

and then use Executor's `awaitTermination` in order to wait both tasks to complete.